# distortion in textField

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a bitmap data which draw a text field. after scaling, text are distortion.
I using following code:

```
// tf is text Field and bm is bitmap.
var tf:TextField = new TextField();
tf.text = "Hello world";
var bd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(200, 200, true, 0x00ff00);
bd.draw(tf);
var bm:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bd);
addChild(bm);
bm.scaleX = 2;
bm.scaleY = 2;
```

Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

You should use transform matrix to draw an upscaled text field (or any other vector graphics object) onto a BitmapData.

```
var mat:Matrix=new Matrix();
mat.scale(2.0,2.0);
bd.draw(tf,mat);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, increase the font size and then convert and scale as bitmap like so,

```
//---- Text format ----
var textFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
textFormat.font = "Arial";
//textFormat.bold = true;
textFormat.size = 40;
//---------------------------------------------

//
var tf:TextField = new TextField();
tf.text = "Hello world";
/*tf.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
tf.gridFitType = GridFitType.PIXEL;
tf.thickness = 0;
tf.sharpness = 0;*/
tf.setTextFormat(textFormat);
//

//
var bd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(200,200,true,0x00ff00);
bd.draw(tf);
var bm:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bd);
bm.smoothing = true;
addChild(bm);

bm.scaleX = 2;
bm.scaleY = 2;
```

Best luck.